# django filter horizontal without ordering

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

In a django model containing a `many-to-many` field and displayed in admin with a `filter horizontal`, Is it possible to disable the default ordering so that picked entries in the filter are not reordered alphabetically?
In that case, It would be to alter the order of the selected entries in the filter horizontal only by the order they have been picked.

Comment: what do you mean they are re-ordered? When you pick them, the latest pick appears at the bottom, no-reordering takes place. After you save and re-open the view, they are ordered the same way as the default queryset order. If you want to keep the order as they were picked, you'd have to actually save that in the model relationship. You can use a package like django-adminsortable for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this. The package gives you a SortedFilteredSelectMultiple - a widget that retains order of selected items and allows you to change it.

https://github.com/svleeuwen/sortedm2m-filter-horizontal-widget

Comment: It works like a charm! Thks. Just a few undocumented tips: Of course, sortedm2m has to be installed first and follow the migration instructions. When registered in 'INSTALLED_APPS', both have to be placed before any custom app of your project. Also, remove the new sorted filed from your filter horizontal if any ;).